# jquery unhandled exception how to handle this exception

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

Unhandled exception at line 3, column 147 in http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js

0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'

Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title> Login form </title>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #17a2b8;
  height: 100vh;
}
#login .container #login-row #login-column #login-box {
  margin-top: 120px;
  position :center;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 320px;
  border: 1px solid #9C9C9C;
  background-color: #EAEAEA;
}
#login .container #login-row #login-column #login-box #login-form {
  padding: 20px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="login">
        <h3 class="text-center text-white pt-5">Login form</h3>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="login-row" class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <div id="login-column" class="col-md-6">
                    <div id="login-box" class="col-md-12">
                        <form id="login-form" class="form" action="" method="post">
                            <h3 class="text-center text-info">Login</h3>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="username" class="text-info">Employee ID :</label><br>
                                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password" class="text-info">Password:</label><br>
                                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">

                                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-md" value="submit">
                            </div>                           
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

above code generates exception

Comment: Please provide _your_ code so we can get a more rounded understanding of what you're trying to achieve / what's being called where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found your issue please add jquery before the bootstrap script

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title> Login form </title>
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">

  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background-color: #17a2b8;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    
    #login .container #login-row #login-column #login-box {
      margin-top: 120px;
      position: center;
      max-width: 600px;
      height: 320px;
      border: 1px solid #9C9C9C;
      background-color: #EAEAEA;
    }
    
    #login .container #login-row #login-column #login-box #login-form {
      padding: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="login">
    <h3 class="text-center text-white pt-5">Login form</h3>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="login-row" class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div id="login-column" class="col-md-6">
          <div id="login-box" class="col-md-12">
            <form id="login-form" class="form" action="" method="post">
              <h3 class="text-center text-info">Login</h3>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username" class="text-info">Employee ID :</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password" class="text-info">Password:</label><br>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">

                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-md" value="submit">
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: : I am facing same exception still after moving the jquery script before bootstrap script.

Comment: Please provide your custom script

Comment: there is no custom script as such, the exception is showing while executing jquery.min.js(dynamic)

Comment: Which browser you can use?

Comment: internet explorer

Comment: You can add meta like this <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> if this meta  add after not solve your issue add  jquery lower version

Comment: I am glad I could help. :)